# LPWAN technology for remote environmental monitoring

Tags: lora, lorawan, lpwan, sigfox

What would be the most appropriate **LPWAN** technologies for environmental monitoring in a remote area, given the following:

- The monitoring system would be made up of **3 to 10 nodes** located within a circular (star) pattern with a diameter of at least **5 km**.
- Each node sends data on a **minute**'s basis.
- The location is a **rural/forested** area on hilly terrain in Slovenia (southern central **Europe**)
- The nodes should be **energy efficient**, however there is a possibility of connecting a central node (**gateway**) to mains power and the internet using Ethernet.

I am mostly looking into the following technologies:

- **GPRS** (coverage in the area is not ideal, high energy consumption, sunsetting technology)
- **NB-IoT** (not yet adopted by network carriers, unknown date)
- **[Sigfox](https://www.sigfox.com/en)** (no coverage, possibility of deploying a [Micro Base Station](https://www.sigfox.com/en/news/sigfox-opens-its-network-brand-new-micro-base-station))
- **[Ingenu](https://www.ingenu.com/)** (most promising technology, no info on coverage or local base station possibilities)
- **[LoRaWAN](https://lora-alliance.org/about-lorawan)** (no coverage, possibility of deploying a [gateway](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/gateways/))

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that with LoRaWAN (and others ISM technologies), you have to follow the local regulation about duty cycle as you will use ISM radio band.

If you are at a distance of around 5km, you may need to use a large spreading factor meaning you will spread the data on air, and so use more airtime.

In Europe, you have (basically) 1% of air time allow. See this [acticle](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/lorawan/duty-cycle.html)

So to be able to send every minutes, you payload must be very short or you must use a smaller spreading factor, to comply with regulation. To get a idea you can is this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QvcKsGeTTPpr9icj4XkKXq4r2zTc2j0gsHLrnplzM3I/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1):

I did a case study on [LoRaWAN](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/) in 2015. Since then the community is continuously growing. The case study was about installing one Gateway in our city.

I find it one of the best solution because

- Low power consumption (As a node reports to [Gateway](https://uk.farnell.com/the-things-network/ttn-gw-868/the-things-gateway-eu/dp/2675813), 3 AAA batteries lasts for more than a month)
- Low cost devices ([The Things Uno](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/devices/uno/))
- Long range wireless network (Up to [10 km or 6 miles](https://uk.farnell.com/the-things-network/ttn-gw-868/the-things-gateway-eu/dp/2675813))
- Huge community support ([Communities](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/community))
- Future plans to support multiple Bluetooth Broadcast/Mesh networks. ([Topology options](https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-technology/topology-options))